# Goodness of fit shows less than 0.01 p-values at all 16 distributions for my wind data

Tags: distributions, goodness-of-fit, weibull-distribution

I have got two wind datasets (one for 4 months and the other one for 12 years). Typically wind speed distributions follow Weibull distributions. In order to demonstrate my data distribution in a statistically sound manner, I ran goodness of fit test in Minitab. However, all p-values of 16 distributions including Weibull distribution showed extremely low (<0.01). I have no idea what to do next as all distributions do not fit with my data.. 
Weibull distributions showed lowest AD values though. Can I use it to support that my data has Weibull distributions? Below is the description of my test result.

Descriptive Statistics

```
   N  N*     Mean    StDev  Median    Minimum  Maximum  Skewness   Kurtosis
2894   0  15.8579  8.69187   14.56  0.0533333    44.42  0.521124  -0.317979


Box-Cox transformation: Lambda = 0.573785

Johnson transformation function:
0.910617 + 1.25421 * Ln( ( X + 2.42013 ) / ( 50.6894 - X ) )


Goodness of Fit Test

Distribution                  AD       P  LRT P
Normal                    21.568  <0.005
Box-Cox Transformation     2.035  <0.005
Lognormal                 52.753  <0.005
3-Parameter Lognormal      4.050       *  0.000
Exponential              236.204  <0.003
2-Parameter Exponential  233.814  <0.010  0.000
Weibull                    1.779  <0.010
3-Parameter Weibull        1.514  <0.005  0.000
Smallest Extreme Value    77.762  <0.010
Largest Extreme Value      4.727  <0.010
Gamma                     10.989  <0.005
3-Parameter Gamma          2.917       *  0.000
Logistic                  20.538  <0.005
Loglogistic               23.023  <0.005
3-Parameter Loglogistic    8.249       *  0.000
Johnson Transformation     0.622   0.106


ML Estimates of Distribution Parameters

Distribution             Location    Shape     Scale  Threshold
Normal*                  15.85790            8.69187
Box-Cox Transformation*   4.68271            1.59250
Lognormal*                2.56056            0.74667
3-Parameter Lognormal     3.37633            0.28606  -14.61547
Exponential                                 15.85790
2-Parameter Exponential                     15.81003    0.04787
Weibull                            1.86662  17.81083
3-Parameter Weibull                1.97275  18.54109   -0.58137
Smallest Extreme Value   20.39570            9.29332
Largest Extreme Value    11.74217            7.24790
Gamma                              2.61645   6.06084
3-Parameter Gamma                  5.10250   3.94816   -4.28763
Logistic                 15.31511            5.03370
Loglogistic               2.63670            0.38443
3-Parameter Loglogistic   3.22306            0.19638  -10.52426
Johnson Transformation*  -0.01235            1.01633

* Scale: Adjusted ML estimate
```

Comment: 1) If you're doing a Box-Cox transformation and then fitting to a Weibull, the data itself isn't distributed Weibull, 2) What is your time stamp?  Wind speeds are highly correlated over short time intervals, and also have very strong patterns within the day, typically.  3) A small goodness-of-fit p-value basically means either "this distribution is a poor fit to the data" or "I have a lot of data, so no off-the-shelf distribution will pass a GoF test", with some mixture of the two for intermediate sample sizes.

Comment: In addition to excellent points made by @jbowman, quantile-quantile plots are worth more than this kind of testing. Dependence messes up the P-values, any way. Then the real "test" is not based on P-value, but that one distribution manifestly is closer to the data.

Comment: Another comment: If the values can be considered as realizations of iid random variables, thanks to your large sample, you can estimate the true distribution function very precisely by the ECDF with confidence band. Depending on the scientific question, it might not be necessary to stick to a distribution that happens to have a name.

Comment: Yet more: for skewed environmental data, I am most interested in whether the fit for most of the distribution is about right and the fit for the far tail is not too lousy. For that I am not convinced that Anderson-Darling is associated with a good figure of merit.

Comment: I bet wind-speed is *never* exactly Weibull; at best it will be a useful approximation. Nor will it be exactly any of the other distributions you may be able to test for. One wonders, then, why you would test at all? (In any case hypothesis tests are a poor way to do model selection) When you say "all distributions do not fit with my data" ... that's nonsense. There are a lot more than 16 possibilities! But why try to 'fit' distributions *at all*? You've got a nice large sample; if you can treat it as iid (which I seriously doubt), you have plenty of information there in your sample.

Comment: @jbowman Hello jbowman, thank you for your comment again for me. 1) I did not transformed my data through a Box-Cox transformation. 2) time interval is 30min. Yep I acknowledge that there are daily and seasonal wind patterns. 3)I have two datasets in different time range: one is for 2 month with 2 min interval, the other one is for 12 years with 30min interval. I was confused because both datasets showed very low p-values on the test.

Comment: @Glen_b as you said Glen, weather data is not treated as iid. Based on my poor knowledge of statistics, I thought more samples will have a closer representation of true distribution of wind. I used all raw data to get a more accurate analysis of the true distribution.

Comment: @NickCox If dependence messes up the P-values, then p-value may not be appropriate to use as an indicator of fitness of the distributions to my data. thanks for the point!

Comment: @Glen_b A large body of work by people who know enough statistics to be dangerous is predicated on the Weibull dist'n for wind speed.  This assumption was originally "validated" using a remarkably small sample size (I read the original paper a few years ago, but can't remember the exact number.)  It's really convenient when combined with the standard formula for adjusting windspeed at a particular elevation (e.g., 10 meters) to other elevations (e.g., 3 meters) given a "roughness" parameter for surface terrain.  I never found it all that good a fit in my work, though.

Comment: Kangmin I was insufficiently clear - while an identically distributed (unconditional on prior values) values in a sufficient-size sample - even a dependent one - will allow us to get information about the common distribution, the dependence structure allows us to say much more. But I'd assume that not only is there dependence, but structure in the mean (for example) over time that makes it not identically distributed.

Comment: @jbowman I have little doubt it's a convenient and likely useful approximation in many circumstances for this problem. My main aim was to convey to the OP that in large samples, there should be little surprise that it - and any other convenient, simple distribution - would be rejected by a reasonably powerful test.

Comment: One other issue I forgot to mention on top of everything else (such as dependence affecting the distribution of the AD), is that the A-D is a test for a fully-specified distribution. Unless you adjust the distribution of the test statistic for the estimation of parameters, the distribution of the test statistic won't be what you'll get under the null when you estimate parameters. Another issues is that no goodness of fit test will tell you what distribution your data has - it can only give you an indication that it's not consistent with some distribution. ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... Failure to say 'it's not consistent with X' (i.e. non-rejection) is not the same thing as saying 'it has distribution X'.